# Uncertainty in astropy QTable

Tags: python, astropy

While `uncertainty` is supported in `NDDataArray` I can't figure out how to create a `QTable` with such data.

Is that possible?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by create a QTable with uncertainty?  What do you want it to do?  To what do the uncertainties apply?  A specific column in the table?

Comment: @Iguananaut, I mean using `QTable` as one would use `NDDataArray` with uncertainties, but with benefits of Table. So every element may come with its uncertainties, and when calculating means and other statistics over columns, or operations between the columns (addition) I would like to have errors calculations performed automatically.